Adding fixed value to create and update in Laravel using Backpack
Was wondering what would be the right way to this?
Trying out Backpack and ran into simple issue. I have Post and User and there is User hasMany Post relation. Now since I have CrudController how would go about setting current backpack_user() as Post User. I mean I can hook model events (https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/eloquent#events) and do it that way, but it seems bit of an hassle. Didn't find from Backpack docs whether there is better way or not.
tried to add $this->crud->model->user()->associate(backpack_user()); to setupCreateOperation and setup in my PostCrudController backpack just ignores these.

Finally found https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/6.x/crud-operation-create#use-events-in-your-setup-method in the docs. This provides clear solution to the issue
Post::creating(function($entry) {
    $entry->user()->associate(backpack_user());
});

